# local compactness property proof closure compact

Tags: general-topology, solution-verification

Definition:

A hausdorff space $X$ in which each $p\in X$ has a neighborhood with compact closure is said to be $\textbf{locally compact}$

Problem:

Let $X$ be a locally compact space. If $p\in X$ and $U$ is a neighborhood of $p$, then there exists a neighborhood $V$ of $p$ with compact closure such that $p\in \overline{V}\subseteq U$.

My attempt:

To see this, note that by local compactness, there exists a neighborhood $W$ of $p$ with compact closure. Now consider the open set $W\cap U\owns p$. As $\overline{W\cap U}$ is contained in $\overline{W}$, it must therefore be compact. Indeed, set $V=W\cap U$.

Is this proof correct?

Comment: No. Better idea: use that $\overline{W}$ is normal and apply this to the relatively open $U \cap W$.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma what's wrong about it? Is it that we can only conclude that $\overline{W\cap U}$ is compact in $\overline{W}$? and not $X$?

Comment: Why would $\overline{V} \subseteq U$ hold for your $V$? compactness does not depend on the surrounding space BTW.

Comment: OH right. ofcourse

Comment: It is possible that $V = U$.